# Matching a list of names to a column with bad data quality (Python)

Tags: python, n-gram

I have a table with 5 columns, one of which is a list of names in terrible data quality. I managed to clean it up as far as possible in R, but it still looks something like this (formatted as code for easier reading):

```
Neville Longbottomx
Severus Snape Slyth
Granger, Hermioone
Miss Lovegoo
Nott: Theodore
Mr Potter Gryffindor
Malfoy, Draco
Bulstrode, Millicent
McGonagall, Minerv
Seamus Finnigan Mister
Miss Abbott, Hannah
Ernie Macmillan M
Dumbledore, Albus
Parkinson, Pans" Slyth
```

Now, I have another list with names like this:

```
Lovegood, Luna
Longbottom, Neville
Macmillan, Ernie
Nott, Theodore
Parkinson, Pansy
```

And I want to find the names in the second list in the first one. I looked up different articles on this and tried [this method](https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html) because ngrams seemed like a smart way to go, but I first got this error:

```
def ngrams(string, n=3):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD',r'', string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]


company_names = names['NAMECOLUMN']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(company_names)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-687c2896bcf2>", line 17, in <module>
    tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(company_names)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1305, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 752, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):

  File "<ipython-input-4-687c2896bcf2>", line 10, in ngrams
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD',r'', string)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 182, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

And after trying it as a string:

```
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

I'm not even sure that I'm going in the right direction with this but it was the best link I could find that corresponded with what I need to do, and I'm not sure what I need to do better. It doesn't help that I'm a complete noob with Python :( So I hope you have some patience with me.

Alas, I'd be super grateful for suggestions on how to deal with the above problem and/or code.

Thanks so much in advance!!

**Edit:** Completely forgot to mention that the ideal solution would match & grab the complete row from my ugly table, as I need the information stored in the other columns for the names.

Comment: So here's the question ... What is your expected output for your example

Comment: may be problem is in `string` argument. May be `ngrams()` gets not string type

Comment: @RushabhMehta The desired result would be to figure out which rows in the big column in my table correspond to the names list. I had first just added the rows from the "search name" list to the big column, hoping I would get matches that way. If there's another way I'm open to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fuzzy matching algorithms :)

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

a = ['Neville Longbottomx','Severus Snape Slyth','Granger, Hermioone','Miss Lovegoo',
    'Nott: Theodore','Mr Potter Gryffindor','Malfoy, Draco','Bulstrode, Millicent',
    'McGonagall, Minerv','Seamus Finnigan Mister','Miss Abbott, Hannah','Ernie Macmillan M',
    'Dumbledore, Albus','Parkinson, Pans" Slyth']

b = ['Lovegood, Luna','Longbottom, Neville','Macmillan, Ernie','Nott, Theodore','Parkinson, Pansy']
get_match_a = []
for name1 in b:
    for name2 in a:
        if fuzz.partial_ratio(name2,name1)>50: # Tune this to fit your need
            get_match_a.append(name2)
            #print(name1,':',name2,'||',fuzz.partial_ratio(name2,name1))
            #uncomment above to see the matching
```

As you can see below, it works very well. I hope this will guide you to where you want to go :)[image]

Comment: which os are you using? and are you in the same environment that you install fuzzywuzzy? :) and did you read https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/78

Comment: Hah, I was just being dumb! Installing it with pip instead of conda worked. Now it's telling me "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()", although I just..don't even understand where a float would be in that column of names.

Comment: Can you share the code that generates that error? ;)

Comment: Can you also print lstA and lstB  and take screenshots?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CRlysTs and https://imgur.com/a/jOInnNP , those are just the first two rows of each :)

Comment: Try to cast values to string. E.g. str(name1)! I just don’t see where you get that float from. Try using Error handling. try: your code except TypeError:pass.

Comment: It works super great now!!! Thank you so much! Do you happen to have any idea how I could fetch the whole rows from the matching names along with them? :)

Comment: Yes! If you are using Pandas, you can use both df.loc[row,:] or df.iloc[row,:] . Or you coulis set names to index. Can you share what you have?

Comment: Hey! Just wanted you to know that I finished it yesterday, and it works perfectly now. This is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/QSkU7r0 Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Awesome. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a look at `fuzzywuzzy` package to do this kind of matching. For your needs, I think filtering names with `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` or `fuzz.token_set_ratio` score greater than a certain threshold (say 75%) would be enough

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> 
>>> lstA = ['Neville Longbottomx', 'Severus Snape Slyth', 'Granger, Hermioone', 'Miss Lovegoo', 'Nott: Theodore', 'Mr Potter Gryffindor', 'Malfoy, Draco', 'Bulstrode, Millicent', 'McGonagall, Minerv', 'Seamus Finnigan Mister', 'Miss Abbott, Hannah', 'Ernie Macmillan M', 'Dumbledore, Albus', 'Parkinson, Pans" Slyth']
>>> lstB = ['Lovegood, Luna', 'Longbottom, Neville', 'Macmillan, Ernie', 'Nott, Theodore', 'Parkinson, Pansy']
>>> 
>>> dict((name,next(takewhile(lambda n: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(n, name)>75, lstA), '')) for name in lstB)
{'Lovegood, Luna': '', 'Longbottom, Neville': 'Neville Longbottomx', 'Macmillan, Ernie': '', 'Nott, Theodore': '', 'Parkinson, Pansy': ''}
```

Comment: what! I had a similar answer :) It appears that we were answering at the same time.

Comment: Yeah... happens sometimes :). Upvoted for suggesting `fuzzywuzzy`

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your suggestion :) I converted both data frames to lists, but when I run the code through, it only returns a list of the names from my search list as 'Longbottom, Neville': '' and so on, even though there are definite matches in there. :(

Comment: Does your list same as `lstA`. If not, please post it here

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v3456i3 here's how I converted it (UPTEXT and Displayname are the relevant columns). The no-matches look like up there in your comment. :(

Comment: @Lena. Can you print lstA and lstB before the `dict` call

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong right now, but if I use the HP names I'm getting lists within a list: https://imgur.com/a/DMmvhdv my "real" name list is just a normal list looking like yours up there though.

Comment: For a quick soln, you can flatten your list by doing `lstA = [e for sl in lstA for e in sl]`. But you should ask a question in SO on how to onvert your dataframe to list properly.